# remote connection problem to sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I'm having a problem making a remote connection to SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008. There must be a simple step I'm missing somewhere, so if anyone can determine what it is, I would really appreciate it.

I can connect to the database from a web page (from the same server) and from Sql Server Management Studio (logging in using RDC and running it from the server). I would like to be able to connect from a client machine, to manage the database or use a SqlDataSource on an ASP .NET web page in VS. When I try to do either of things, I get "Named Pipes Provider, Error 40, Could not open a connection to Sql Server."

The following summarizes the steps I've taken to enable a remote connection:
- made sure all Sql services are running (including Browser Service)
- enabled Named Pipes and TCP (Port 1433)
- enabled remote connection in Sql Server Management Studio
- created an exception in Windows Firewall for Port 1433
- checked the Error Log to see if the server is listening on the correct port.

Here's a few pertinent lines from the log (timestamps removed):
Server,Unknown,Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1  1434].
Server,Unknown,Server is listening on [ ::1  1434].
Server,Unknown,Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\sql\query ].
Server,Unknown,Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ].
Server,Unknown,Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433].
Server,Unknown,Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433].

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value for `IP All->TCP Dynamic Ports` to an empty value in the Sql Server Configuration Manager int the TCP protocol properties window.

Comment: It's already set to an empty value, so not using Dynamic Ports. Thanks for answering